# How can I get time period in years-months format?

Tags: java, date

I have two strings like `"March 2012"` and  `"April 2013"`.  I need to subtract these dates and get something like: `"1 year 2 month"`.

I know how to get it in days:

```
df.parse(secondDate).getTime() - df.parse(firstDate).getTime())/(1000*60*60*24)
```

but I will receive 395 days. How can I get it in years-month format? I know it should be easy but I cannot guess how to do that.

Comment: it 1  year 1 month not 2 month

Comment: If you aren't concerned about leap years, try `/ 365` and `% 365`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of problem, it is best to use the new [Java Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) that was introduced in Java 8.

We have 2 Strings that represent a year and a month. Therefore, we will parse each String into a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object using a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The month names are in their long English form so we will use the pattern `"MMMM yyyy"`.

Once they are parsed, we can get the period between those two temporal objects with [`Period.between`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-). This method takes a `LocalDate` as parameter so we need to add a day to each `YearMonth`: here, we will set it to the first day of the month (what matters is that both are set to the same day).

Finally, [`getYears()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getYears--) return the amount of years in this period and [`getMonths()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getMonths--) returns the amount of month.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String startStr = "March 2012";
    String endStr = "April 2013";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    YearMonth start = YearMonth.parse(startStr, formatter);
    YearMonth end = YearMonth.parse(endStr, formatter);

    Period period = Period.between(start.atDay(1), end.atDay(1));

    System.out.println(period.getYears() + " years and " + period.getMonths() + " months.");
    // prints "1 years and 1 months." (you could add check for the pluralization of course ;) )
}
```

With this method, you don't need to worry about tricky considerations, it is handled automatically by the API.

Answer (score -2):

Make use of the Java8 API `java.time.Period`, which gives you a date-based amount of time:

```
Period p = Period.between(firstDate, secondDate);
System.out.println(p.getYears()+" years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, and " + p.getDays() + " days.");
```

Comment: How is that any different that my answer which provides more explanation?

Answer (score -2):

Check the below example, it should work correctly and solve leap year case as depend on year and month only:

```
     public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

    //some data initilzation for the sample
    Date d1 = new Date(), d2 = new Date();
    d1.setYear(d1.getYear() - 1); //Just for the sample, replace it with your dates
    d1.setMonth(d1.getMonth() + 5);//Just for the sample, replace it with your dates

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(d1);
    int year1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(d2);
    int year2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

    int yearDiff = year2 - year1;
    int monthDiff = month2 - month1;

    //Logic, in case d1  Jul 2015 and d2 Feb 2016, the need to reduce one year and put the remaining months on monthDiff value
    if (monthDiff < 0) {
        yearDiff = yearDiff - 1;
        monthDiff = monthDiff + 12;
    }

    System.out.println(" " + d1);
    System.out.println(" " + d2);

    System.out.println("yearDiff " + yearDiff + "     " + "monthsDiff " + monthDiff);

}
```

Comment: Ow god. You do know [`Date.setYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setYear-int-) has been deprecated since Java 1.1, i.e. 7 major versions ago?

Comment: Please read the comment on the code "//some data initilzation for the sample".
just for sample preparation and testing. Right?

Comment: So? Are you recommending the usage of deprecated API, that has been deprecated since more than 10 years?

Comment: Please update your voting if you see the example is corrected.

Comment: I won't. It's a code-only answer, as such, it's not a good and helpful answer. Plus, you still use deprecated APIs. You should try to make your contributions unique and distinctive, not just code-dumps. Stack Overflow is all about this. Please read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

You can customize the below code as your need:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MyClass tdt = new MyClass();
        System.out.println("Date: "+tdt.doSubtractMath("31/10/2000","31/12/2016").getTime());
    }
    /**
    * method to create a calendar object, subtract time, and return result
    */
    private Calendar doSubtractMath(String firstDate, String secondDate) throws Exception
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yyyy");

        Calendar secondDateCalender = Calendar.getInstance();

        secondDateCalender.setTime(sdf.parse(secondDate));


        Calendar firstDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        firstDateCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(firstDate));

        secondDateCalender.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1 * firstDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        secondDateCalender.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1 * firstDateCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));

        secondDateCalender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1 * firstDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        secondDateCalender.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1 * firstDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        return secondDateCalender;

    }
}
```

Comment: The given code is not self-explanatory. Dates are a tricky business and it's not obvious at all while the given code would work. What about leap years? Please provide more explanation in text. Code-only answers are discouraged. Also, please at least format it properly...

Comment: The given code will subtract firstDate from secondDate. It does not matter whether leap year or not.

Comment: Come on, it doesn't even respect the format String of the OP... Please read [answer] and try to improve your contributions.